# In a RegEx I need to allow spaces only in middle and prevent spaces at beginning and end

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, regex-negation

I have a requirement wherein I have below requiements to validate a name field:

1. don't allow following symbols: `&(¥)*/+}{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!"#&\|-'
2. can´t contain numbers
3. can´t contain blank spaces at the begining or at the end

I have used below regex:

```
^[^\\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\\\{¿?¡_^~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]*$
```

It is fulfilling all the conditions except that is is also restricting spaces in between the string. For ex:

It restricts format: "firstname lastname"

I need the above format to be allowed. I only need to restrict spaces at beginning and end.

Comment: Do you allow, say **□◊≠∞‡**? What symbols do you accept? Say name must start from letter, can contain letters, digits and spaces, must end with digit or letter?

Comment: if you use javascript for the regex, why not simply use a `trim()` function before testing? you can then remove space from your excludes

Comment: Is 2 space in a row in the First name ok ?

Comment: my guess is that you shouldn't really restrict spaces at beginning or end. you should simply trim string by space so any input starting or ending with space will be trimmed.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/pinMdq/1.

Comment: By the way dash are allowed in French name: Jean-Michel, and in hyspanic name: José-Maria. And arabic name too: Mohammed al-Jamil.

Comment: most (European) languages I know allow hyphenated first and last names (hyphens in last names when marrying and wanting to keep both names)

Comment: With `.` allowed `.... ....` is a valid name. The issue with name and reg exp is that, it's never clear why you have to control it. For security purpuse (no boby ';  drop table)? For user readability (John won't use I||||I||I||II| as name)

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew . Your answer worked like a wonder! :) was stuck with this since last 1 day. Sigh of relief now.

Comment: Thanks every one for guiding me wrt my question. It is solved now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it is used in some kind of a RegularExpressionAttribute validation, and you just want to use a single pattern for this.

You have already the first building block:

```
[^\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]
```

This matches any char but the ones defined in the set. It does not match whitespace. If you quantify with `*` and wrap with anchors, no whitespace will be allowed anywhere in the string. So, you just need to add an optional group (quantified with `*` or `?` or `{x,y}` depending on how many spaces you want to allow):

```
^[^\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]+(?:\s[^\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]+)*$
                                        ^^^                                         ^^
```

If you want to also match an empty string, wrap the pattern with an optional non-capturing group:

```
^(?:[^\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]+(?:\s[^\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]+)*)?$
 ^^^                                                                                     ^^
```

Escape backslashes as needed.

As for the hyphen in the names: it might be appropriate to allow it in the same place as whitespace:

```
^(?:[^\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]+(?:[\s-][^\s0-9&(¥)*/+}\\{¿?¡_^`~¨¬;:@!#&\"|-]+)*)?$
                                              ^^^^^
```